# Using the openNTF Domino API as a dependency in Plugin dev

Tags: java, osgi, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have been using the openNTF Domino API (ODA) for a while now and am very happy with it. In fact I am so happy that I want to use it with my own OSGi Plug-ins as dependencies, and I am having trouble with that.

The following is what is going on.

1. When I just start the plug in and do not use anything from ODA, everything is good.  I can select my new library as required in Notes Designer and I can use my classes and all seems well.
2. The second thing I do is I go into the /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and I mark org.openntf.domino as a dependency.  From what i see, this is the correct plug in because it contains the ODA Document, View, Session etc. Classes that i want to make use of.  If I should be using a different plug-in, please tell me.
3. I go into my class which extends the com.ibm.xsp.library.AbstractXspLibrary and I get a little stuck with the Library.getDependencies().  I am not really certain what to include here to mark my dependency on ODA.  I have tried a few different strings, but in the end, I am not even sure if I need to mark it here as a dependency.

I have tried:

```
"org.openntf.domino"
"org.openntf.domino.xsp"
"org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspLibrary"
```

I think I tried a few other things but cannot exactly remember what.

The main issue is that I can no longer select my plug-in library in Notes Designer and I cannot use it(obviously).  So my question is, how do I correctly add my dependency to other plug-ins installed separately?  I will not only be using ODA, but also the ExtLibs.

I am very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that "org.openntf.domino.xsp" depends on "org.openntf.domino.plugin", in the same way I think you want your library to depend on ODA. It also depends on Extension Library. Looking at that, my suggestion is to try:

1. On plugin.xml, Dependencies tab, add "org.openntf.domino.xsp". This tells it to look for that plugins already on the server, otherwise don't run, in which case I think `tell http osgi diag com.myplugin` would throw an error. org.openntf.domino.xsp is already dependent on org.openntf.domino.plugin, so that's the only plugin you need as a dependency.
2. I don't think you'll need to tick "Reexport this dependency". I think you'd do that if you didn't want to install the ODA plugin on the server itself as well. Also, I don't think you'll need to add any exported packages on the Runtime tab.
3. In getDependencies(), add "org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspLibrary". This loads the XspLibrary class when you load your XspLibrary.

Comment: This works as long as I do not include the the plugin as a dependency.  The only thing I could add was org.openntf.domino.xsp, which also seems to be enough.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: sorry, I meant "org.openntf.domino.plugin" should not be included in order for it to work.  (Unless I did something else stupid)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. org.openntf.domino.xsp plugin already has org.openntf.domino.plugin as a dependency. So you only need to include org.openntf.domino.xsp on the Deoendencies tab. I've updated my answer accordingly.